# Xcode 12 and Algolia Search Client?

Tags: device, algolia, xcode12

since Update Xcode12 I get this error Massage:

Showing Recent Messages
The package product 'Logging' requires minimum platform version 9.0 for the iOS platform, but this target supports 8.0

The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99.

This is how the Package.swift file looks like form Algolia. Can I solve it or do I have to wait for next update ?

import PackageDescription

```
let package = Package(
    name: "AlgoliaSearchClient",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v8),
        .macOS(.v10_10),
        .watchOS(.v2),
        .tvOS(.v9)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "AlgoliaSearchClient",
            targets: ["AlgoliaSearchClient"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url:"https://github.com/apple/swift-log.git", from: "1.3.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "AlgoliaSearchClient",
            dependencies: ["Logging"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "AlgoliaSearchClientTests",
            dependencies: ["AlgoliaSearchClient", "Logging"])
    ]
)
```

Comment: Facing same issues. Any luck on your side?

Comment: Hi, I'm also facing the same issue, did you figure it out ??? plz reply

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem yesterday , I used pod instead package, after the error disappeared